# Ruby on rails, facebook login get friends and AccessToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an app with a facebook login using :

```
gem "koala"
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
gem 'fb_graph2'
```

I want to get access to **user friends who use the app too**. 
But I don't know how to do that and how to have the 'access token' because I don't understand what is the access token ...

Right now, here is the code that I have.
models/ user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :provider, type: String
  field :uid, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :picture, type: String
  field :auth_token, type: String

  has_many :parties
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => 'Invite', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => 'Invite', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'

  has_many :friends

  # TODO: Ajouter les amitiés
  # TODO: Ajouter les recherches d'amis (livereload)

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth['provider']
      user.uid = auth['uid']
      user.auth_token = auth['credentials']['token']
      if auth['info']
         user.name = auth['info']['name'] || ""
         user.picture = auth['info']['image'] || ""
      end
    end
  end

  def large_image
    return "http://graph.facebook.com/#{self.uid}/picture?type=large"
  end

  def normal_image
    return "http://graph.facebook.com/#{self.uid}/picture?type=normal"
  end


end
```

controllers / sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.where(:provider => auth['provider'],
                      :uid => auth['uid']).first || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Signed out!'
  end

  def new
    redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Authentication error: #{params[:message].humanize}"
  end
end
```

initializer / omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '<public_key>', '<private_key>'
end
```

And my friends controller :

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:code]
      session[:access_token] = session[:oauth].get_access_token(params[:code])
    end
    # auth established, now do a graph call:
    @api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:access_token])
    @user_profile = @api.get_object("me")
    @friends = @api.get_connections(@user_profile['id'], "friends")

  end
end
```

It don't work, I have this error :

```
type: OAuthException, code: 2500, message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., x-fb-trace-id: BeOG6OGemO9 [HTTP 400]
```

I imagine that it's because my code is not correct, so I hope someone should help me improve my code and get access to user friends !

Answer (score 0):

The token that you saved in `users.auth_token` field is what you need. So when initializing a new `Koala` instance pass users `auth_token` - `@api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.auth_token)` and then try to get friends list, like you do currently.

Regarding what access token is you can read about it here (in Facebook context) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: thank you for the answer buddy ! Actually, I don't have the error anymore, but I don't have my friend list while I have 1 friend in my DB mongo. I have my account and I have an other account that I have created on facebook to test .. and he don't appear on the friends page, do you know why ?

Comment: Could you be more specific? It's hard to understand what exactly is not working from your description

Comment: Yes ! I have 2 facebook account, both are friends, and both are registered on my app, but, when I am going to the friends page, where I want to list all my friends who using the app, there is no names, but it's not normal because I should see my 2 facebook account appear because we are friend on facebook and we are both using the app .. is this more clear ? :)

Comment: You should post the relevant code so It is possible to see what you are doing on the back-end.

Comment: On the back end I just record all user info in mongoDB

Comment: All the interesting code is here .. I don't understand what you want to see, don't hesitate to be more specific and I should post it :) with this line : `@friends = @api.get_connections("me", "friends")` I should access to my friend who are using the same app, isn't it ?